# use_frameworks! and Model not found build error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, fastlane

I'm working on a rather large iOS project that was originally written in Objective-C and we're now starting to add in Swift code. We are using Cocoapods to install 3rd party libraries and have included `use_frameworks!` in our Podfile.

In some of our Objective-C classes, we have added module imports at the top such as `@import AFNetworking;`

Usually, on first build of the project within Xcode, the build fails and we see `module 'AFNetworking' not found` but on the second build, it works fine. However, now I am trying to get Fastlane to do our builds and when using Fastlane to do the builds, we get the error 100% of the time.

In the build settings of the target:

- `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` is set to `Yes`
- `Always Search User Paths` is set to `No`
- `User Header Search Paths` is set to `$(SRCROOT)/Pods` and is recursive

Any suggestions on what else I can check/try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I finally found the solution to the problem. Our project is made up of multiple targets (10+) and we noticed that only the one target was failing to build. After hours of hunting around, comparing files we finally looked at the schemes and noticed that the target that wasn't working was using a scheme that had `Find Implicit Dependencies` unchecked. We checked this and it started to build again!

Just to note, the target would build if we built it after building one of the other targets but if you then deleted the derived data and tried to build the target then, it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking "Other Linker Flags" to see if it has the -ObjC value in it?

You can click on your project name on your Navigator, go to Build Settings, scroll down to Linking section and double check on "Other Linker Flags" stated. If it is not there, you can manually add to it.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the `-ObjC` flag is there.